# Phrase to use instead of "Could you please"

Tags: sentence-construction, synonyms

Is there a phrase that can be used in place of

> Could you please

in a formal letter? I have been repeatedly using "Could you please look into", "Could you please let me know" and was wondering if there is something else I can use.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this: [Polite requests - BBC Learnit](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv239.shtml) and [Requests - English Grammar Today, Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/requests)

Comment: @MAKZ Don't use *please* in that position, unless you are trying to annoy people!

Comment: However, I am happier than ever I can imagine should you list phrases you Englive native speaker use frequently or unconciously in your ordinary life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use *please* in this position after the auxiliary verb unless you are annoyed or you are speaking to someone from a position of authority. It could accidentally offend the person you are writing to!  [See here for more details.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64724/using-please-when-assigning-tasks/64753#64753)

Some other phrases you could use are:

- Would it be possible to ...
- Please could you,
- Ideally, we'd like this by
- If you could X, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- Will you be so kind..(as to help me)
- It would be really great if you..(could help me / helped me)
- I'd be grateful if you..(could help me / helped me)

Comment: Will you be so kind as to complete the sentences? While it is obvious what comes after the phrase to someone fluent in English, it may not be to someone less fluent.

Comment: Yeah, by bad. Completed now.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:
I would be obliged (if)...